# Why is it not printing the coding of the void functions?

Tags: c++

Can some help me and explain where i got it wrong?
I just don't know where I'm wrong;C

```
void largest(int);
void smallest(int);
void average(double);

int main()
{
    int n=0,i=1,num,max=0,min=0,sum=0;
    double avg=0;
    
    cout<<"Please enter total number of integers: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"\n";
    
    while (n>0)
    {
        cout<<"Enter integer "<<i<<": ";
        cin>>num;
        
        if (num>max)
        max=num;
        
        if (num<min)
        min=num;
        
        sum=sum+num;
        
        n--;
        i++;
    }
    
    avg=sum/n;
    
    largest(max);
    smallest(min);
    average(avg);
    
    return 0;
}
void largest(int max)
{
    cout<<"The largest integer is: "<<max;
}

void smallest(int min)
{
    cout<<"The smallest integer is: "<<min;
}

void average(double avg)
{
    cout<<"The average is: "<<avg;
}
```

From my understanding im not so sure if this is correct but i need to use void to print out a message and im a bit confuse as to when i should use void and what does the difference between double& and double when i use it?

[image: This is the result I got]
[image: But this is the result I'm going for]

Comment: Also you are doing integer math. The result will be an integer even though you put it in a double.

Comment: You need to divide sum by i, not n

Comment: @vikram actually `i-1` since `i` is initialized to 1, so will be 2 after the 1st iteration, etc

Comment: @RemyLebeau Right:)

Comment: You need to print newline '\n' st the end of each line.

Answer (score 4):

> Process exited ... with return value 3221225620

3221225620 is the numeric code for a `STATUS_INTEGER_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO` (0xC0000094) exception, which means your code is crashing before it has a chance to print out its messages.

On this line:

```cpp
avg=sum/n;
```

`n` is 0 at this point, because the `while` loop above it had decremented `n` on each iteration until `n` reached 0.

To avoid that, change the `while` loop to not modify `n` anymore:

```cpp
while (i <= n)
{
    ...
    i++;
}
```

Or, use a `for` loop instead:

```cpp
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: May want to mention the non-`double` result of `sum/n`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, that is another issue the code has. But the question at hand is regarding why the code is not printing out messages at all.  Not about why it prints out the wrong results. That would be a different question.

Comment: I have corrected my mistake, thank you :D this help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you're dividing by 0, since you're modifying n until it reaches 0 and then use it to divide, it's better if you iterate with another variable instead of reducing the value of n. so the problem isn't that it's not printing, it's that the program dies before reaching that